# Downgrade or compile rsync to fix bug

Tags: ubuntu, rsync

[rsync: [generator] failed to set permissions : Operation not supported (95)](https://serverfault.com/questions/1059618/rsync-generator-failed-to-set-permissions-operation-not-supported-95)

I'm running ubuntu 21.10 and facing the same problem as the above link, but could not follow the solution steps, for e.g. installing libssl-dev gives me this error below:

```
[~/tmp/rsync-be3d6c0fbbd07781bbae6261cda109f8f08c031b]# apt install libssl-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  libssl-doc
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

Also can't comment (ask questions) there due to low reputation, I need my rsync to run, is there a way to downgrade to 3.1.3-8 or some easier solution?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Asking a new question is the correct course of action, and including the link a bonus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

snap installed an older version, not sure how it does it.

```
# snap install rsync --devmode
# rsync -v
rsync  version 3.1.1  protocol version 31
Copyright (C) 1996-2014 by Andrew Tridgell, Wayne Davison, and others.
Web site: http://rsync.samba.org/
```